# Optimal smartcard login option?

Tags: security, smartcard

my Company just started using smartcards when we login in to our computers. Unfortunately, we use the same cards to get access in different parts of our buildings. Often you discover you left your card in the computer at the office forcing you the go back and get it.

My question is two-fold:

1. Wouldn't a better solution be to just use the card when logging in and then remove it. That way your card is always on your person and not in your computer susceptible to theft (for instance at a coffee shop). At least I believe so but I wanted to get a second opinion.
2. Is this login option available on HP smart card readers (HP Elitebook)?

Answer (score 0):

What card login methods are offered, is determined by the operating system, not by the reader. The reader just contributes the state, i.e. card present or absent.

Actually the secure method (as supported by Windows) is, that if you logged in by card, the computer automatically locks, when you extract this card, so if you change the building it is ensured, that your computer is locked. Theft of the card should not be much of a problem in comparison, since it is not overly expensive and can typically be made unusable remotely and quickly; the card is not of much use for the thief in respect to PC access, since the respective PIN is unkown to him/her.

If you prefer convenience over security, a second card for physical access may be an alternative.